# How can I benchmark password strength?

Tags: passwords

My idea was to balance password entropy and memorability.

Is there some tool I can use to benchmark generated passwords?

Would a state of the art password cracking tool measuring the time to crack a given password be a good idea?

Comment: perhaps these help you:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/257611/why-use-random-characters-in-passwords

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/662/what-is-your-way-to-create-good-passwords-that-can-actually-be-remembered

Comment: Don't look at just entropy, there's password topologies to consider as well, see https://github.com/JohannesBuchner/PasswordTopologies

Comment: @Swashbuckler: Your comment is wrong, I am sorry to say that. What you name "topologies" are just rules that some users / companies apply. Any rule means more information about the system, which means less entropy. Means, when you are talking about "topologies" you are talking about reducing entropy compared to a random password generator.

Comment: Closed for now, if the duplicate Q doesn't satisfy your needs feel free to post a *more specific question*, indicating what is missing for you.